# Código php para eliminar no encuentra ruta

Tags: php

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio que requiere subir imágenes y archivos a un servidor web para que los datos estén disponibles remotamente. Instale xampp y estoy usando MySQL perfectamente. Para la subida de archivos tengo un script en PHP que funciona correctamente. Puedo almacenar imágenes sin ningún problema.

Hice este script para eliminar las imágenes:

```
<?php 

    $target_path = $_POST['imagenAEliminar']; 


    if (unlink($_POST['imagenAEliminar'])) {
        echo "[web]Se elimino correctamente.";
    }else{
        if (is_null($_POST['imagenAEliminar'])) {
            echo "[web] Es nulo.";
       }
        echo "[web]Algo sucedio y no se elimino";
    }
?>
```

El envío lo hago por post. Sé que funciona el código porque con:

```
echo $_POST['imagenAEliminar']
```

Me imprime correctamente la ruta que le mandé desde java. Aun así, me da el siguiente error:

> Warning:unlink('imagenesCarrduci/image002.png'):
>
> No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs_e_l_i_m_i_n_a_r.php on line 8

La imagen existe y el directorio es correcto. Si yo pongo

```
unlink('imagenesCarrduci/image002.png');
```

Elimina la imagen correctamente.

No soy muy conocedor de PHP así que estoy un poco embrollado en esto. ¿Por qué puede ocurrir esto? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Este es el código que funciona perfectamente para subir archivos:

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(0);
    $target_path = "imagenes/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
     echo "[web]El archivo ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " ha sido subido";
    } else{
        if (is_null($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])) {

            echo "[web] Es nulo.";

        }   else{

            echo "[web]Ha ocurrido un error, trate de nuevo!";
        }

    }
?>
```

Por si de alguna manera sirve de referencia o ayuda con la solución.

Este es el código que modifique por parte de @Xerif:

```
<?php
  // Defines una CONSTANTE con el directorio raiz + trozo de rura a la carpeta necesaria
 define("RAIZ", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imagenes/');

 chmod(RAIZ.$_POST['imagenAEliminar'], 0755);

 echo RAIZ.$_POST['imagenAEliminar'];
 // añades la RAIZ a unlink
if (unlink(RAIZ.$_POST['imagenAEliminar'])) 
{
    echo "[web]Se elimino correctamente.";
}
else
{
     if (is_null($_POST['imagenAEliminar']))
{
    echo "[web] Es nulo.";
}

    echo "[web]Algo sucedio y no se elimino";
}
```

Este es el error que genera:

> Warning:  chmod(): No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs_e_l_i_m_i_n_a_r.php** on line **5**
> C:/xampp/htdocs/imagenes/image002.png
> **Warning**:  unlink(C:/xampp/htdocs/imagenes/image002.png): Invalid argument in **C:\xampp\htdocs_e_l_i_m_i_n_a_r.php** on line **9**
> [web]Algo sucedio y no se elimino

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Puedes **[tomar el recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. para conocer mas acerca del sitio :) . ¿Estás seguro que la imagen se encuentra en `C:\xampp\htdocs\`? lo pregunto porque no se si es correcto guardar imágenes allí...creo que deberías ver la ruta completa del archivo, esta es una ruta relativa y la otra es absoluta. Mira este [enlace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21306512/4092887) para mas detalles.

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta. La ruta completa es esta: 

 `C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenesCarrduci\image002.png`    

No estoy guardando en `C:\xampp\htdocs`. Lo que se presenta ahí es únicamente el script que genero el error, o eso creo.

Comment: Vamos a ver, el mensaje de error: **`Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs_e_l_i_m_i_n_a_r.php`** te está diciendo **claramente** que hay un error en la ruta del archivo `_e_l_i_m_i_n_a_r.php`, ese archivo que por cierto tiene un nombre tan raaaro. Desde aquí estoy viendo que **al menos** falta una barra invertida \ después de `htdocs`¿sí o no?. Si revisas la parte del código donde llamas ese archivo **es posible, casi seguro, que tengas la ruta mal escrita**.

Comment: Jajaja perdón por el nombre tan raro pero era una "practicas de seguridad". La ruta esta correcta. Cambie el nombre del archivo a algo más formal por si las moscas pero nada que ver. Despues tengo este problema. La ruta la imprimo asi: `C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\image002.png`. La copio tal cual y la pego en el explorador de windows y accesa correctamente. Despues copio esta misma ruta y la pongo directamente en `unlink['C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\image002.png']` y se elimina la foto. Cuando utilizo `$_POST['imagenAEliminar']` y concateno con `imagenes/` todo se va al traste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi recomendación es que utilices rutas absolutas, dan menos problemas:

Puedes hacer algo com esto

```
<?php
// Defines una CONSTANTE con el directorio raiz + trozo de rura a la carpeta necesaria
define("RAIZ", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imagenes/');

// Eliminamos espacios al principio y al final
$post = trim($_POST['imagenAEliminar']);

// Creamos la ruta
$target_path = RAIZ.$post; 

// Mostramos la ruta
echo $target_path;

// añades la RAIZ a unlink
if (unlink($target_path)) 
{
    echo "[web]Se elimino correctamente.";
}
else
{
    if (is_null($_POST['imagenAEliminar']))
    {
        echo "[web] Es nulo.";
    }

    echo "[web]Algo sucedio y no se elimino";
}
?>
```

Así te evitaras dolores de cabeza con rutas relativas.

Por otro lado si quieres usar rutas relativas es recomendable que utilices el **./** (punto, barra) al pincipio para indicar el directorio actual.

Comment: Gracias pero esto se esta volviendo muy frustrante. Elimine todo el código de mi fichero y lo sustituí por el que me mandaste. Cree una nueva carpeta dentro de `htdocs` que se llama `imagenes` tal cual la definiste en el código para descartar caracteres extraños o algo que no este viendo y no funciono.  Recibo el siguiente mesaje:

`Warning:  unlink(C:/xampp/htdocs/imagenes/logo.png): Invalid argument in **C:\xampp\htdocs\_e_l_i_m_i_n_a_r.php** on line **8**
[web]Algo sucedio y no se elimino`

¿Sera posible que la ruta no se reciva como un tipo String? No se como se maneje php.

Comment: Ya corregí la ruta y edite el comentario con el resultado nuevo. Una disculpa por la confusión. Estaba haciendo unas pruebas y cambie el directorio a la raíz. No se a que te refieres con los permisos de la carpeta. Lo investigare.

Comment: No. Todavía no. Tengo otro error. Estoy actualizando la pregunta para mostrarlo con más claridad.

Comment: Entiendo que sea de rutas pero no entiendo por que la ruta que muestra el error sirve para eliminar el archivo si la pongo directamente sobre el script. La ruta esta correcta, pero php no entiende eso y no se por que.

Comment: Implemente el código e imprime esto:

`C:/xampp/htdocs/imagenes/image002.png Warning:  unlink(C:/xampp/htdocs/imagenes/image002.png): Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\_e_l_i_m_i_n_a_r.php on line 11 [web]Algo sucedio y no se elimino`

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el error! El error no era lo que pensaba. El error provenía del código java que estaba implementado. Antes de mandar el post anexa al string "\r\n", caracteres de escape. Cuando llegan php este no los imprime pero si los almacena en el string.

Un amigo revisó el código y pudo darse cuenta de esto en los logs de apache. Borre la linea y todo funciona correcto. Eso me pasa por copiar y pegar pero queda de experiencia.

Y como dice el dicho:

**"EL FLOJO TRABAJA DOS VECES"**

Comment: Que bueno que hayas encontrado la solución. Recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Comment: Pues es raro que mi ejemplo no te funcionase, trim() elimina exactamente esos caracteres (**\t** **\n** **\r** **\0** **\x0B**)  del principio y del final de la cadena. En fin algo tenía que haber.

Comment: Tal vez aplique mal. De todos modos muchas gracias por la ayuda. Fue bastante enriquecedora.